# Entity Framework Code first rename models/tables in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, ef-code-first

I need to upload a project from Visual Studio to Azure, but I have to share the same DB with other projects. So I guess I need to rename all my models that creates the tables in the DB to prevent any conflict with other projetcs model/tables!?

I started to change the name of one the model and then continued to change in the code and also in IdentityModels.cs file, but will this really work? Do I need to change in other files also? One way to simplify it all, would be to use search and replace, but then I have no control of what is changed!

Any good advice how to replace name of table in DB and all instances?

Comment: You can use 1 physical database for more EF models. The table names must be unique. __MigrationsHistory table is shared for more DbContexts... If you have collisions in table naming, consider using the DB schemas.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is a migration plan if you change your model after creating the data base
link : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx